# Three.js BoxGeometry Face Texture flipped

Tags: three.js, textures

I'm going crazy trying to flip the faces of my cube in order to see them in the right direction but I'm not able to come up with anything.
My code is this:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
    renderer.setSize( 990, 350 );
    renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 1);
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        35,             // Field of view
        990 / 350,      // Aspect ratio
        0.1,            // Near plane
        10000           // Far plane
    );
    camera.position.set( 0, 0, -730 );

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 990, 350, 350 );
    geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
    geometry.dynamic = true;
    var materialArray = [];
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'face1.jpg',{},onTextureLoad)}));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'face2.jpg',{},onTextureLoad ) }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'face3.jpg',{},onTextureLoad ) }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'face4.jpg',{},onTextureLoad ), side: THREE.DoubleSide }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'face5.jpg',{},onTextureLoad ) }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'face6.jpg' )}));
    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materialArray);

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );
    mesh.rotation.x  = 360;
    var position = new THREE.Vector3();
    position.setFromMatrixPosition( mesh.matrixWorld );

    camera.lookAt( position );

    var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFFFFFF );
    light.position.set( 10, 0, 10 );
    scene.add( light );

    function animate()
    {
        mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    function onTextureLoad(p)
    {
        p.flipY = false;
    }

    animate();
}
```

And what I get is this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4064417/hosted_images/index.html

What am I supposed to do to see my images correctly flipped?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
I've also tried flipping UV coordinates this way:

```
    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][7] = [new THREE.Vector2(1, 0), new THREE.Vector2(1, 1), new THREE.Vector2(0, 1)];
```

but I don't understand how to set those values in order to obtain my objective.

Comment: don't flip the faces of the cube. flip the textures using gimp or photoshop.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that. The faces are made by clients and I have to assume they are the dumbest as they can be. Maybe the only solution is to put the images in a canvas, flip them and then add the canvas as texture.

Comment: ok then you should not try to flip the faces/vertices of the geometry but the uv coordinates of the faces.

Comment: Ok I've tried that but I was going random since I couldn't figure out how that works.

Comment: can you post the code where you try to change the uv's for faces 3, 4 and 5?

Comment: for which face is that code? I assume you want to flip it horizontally.

Comment: that face is the one with the "4" on the texture. Yes I want to flip them horizontaly (since to flip them vertically there is the texture.flipY property)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][7] = [new THREE.Vector2(0, 0), new THREE.Vector2(0, 1), new THREE.Vector2(1, 1)];
```

Comment: unfortunately [THIS](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4064417/hosted_images/wrong_uv_vertexes.JPG) is the result

Comment: Each box side consists of two faces. You only posted code for one face of one side.

Comment: I looped through all the faces and set to all of them the same vertexes. [HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4064417/hosted_images/uv_coord_wrong_2.JPG) is the result (the same for every face)

Comment: sorry but I did not say that you should apply this change to all faveVertexUvs. Please post your code related to `geometry.faceVertexUvs` (the entire array) so I can see how to fix it.

Comment: I don't have the code you ask me. I'm trying to understand how to write it with your help

Comment: if you have the `geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][7]` you must have the 0..7 entries of the array. post in your question above the entire contents of that array as it stands now.